# Create Table or DataSet from relation between 2 Tables in same DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, database, linq, visual-studio

I've been stuck on this all day.... My love to the person who can solve it!!!!

So, there are 2 Tables

Access Table in (ds.Tables["Access"]) which contains columns of
Barcode, Description, quantity in warehouse etc

and Excel Table in (ds.Tables["Excel"]) which contains columns of
Barcode, quantiy ordered etc however named F2,F4,F8

So how do I get a final DataTable/DataSet (anything that I can .DataSource to on DataGridView) with Excel and Access matched on Barcode????

```
            OleDbConnection conAccess = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\PROGRAMMING.LAB\\geekx_recent.mdb");
        OleDbDataAdapter daAccess = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select Barcode AS BARCODE, quantity AS QTY_WH From Stock", conAccess);

        DataSet dsAll = new DataSet();
        daAccess.Fill(dsAll, "Access");

        OleDbConnection conExcel = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\PROGRAMMING.LAB\\order.xlsx;Extended Properties = Excel 12.0 Xml");
        OleDbDataAdapter daExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT F2 AS BARCODE, F8 AS ORDER_CUST FROM [phil$] WHERE ISNUMERIC(F8)",conExcel);
        daExcel.Fill(dsAll, "Excel");

        DataRelation dr = dsAll.Relations.Add("Excel_Access", dsAll.Tables["Excel"].Columns["BARCODE"], dsAll.Tables["Access"].Columns["BARCODE"], false);
        DataTable dtExcel = dsAll.Tables["Excel"];
        DataTable dtAccess = dsAll.Tables["Access"];
        DataTable dtAll = new DataTable();

        var query = from ex in dtExcel.AsEnumerable()
                    join ac in dtAccess.AsEnumerable()
                    on ex.Field<string>("BARCODE") equals ac.Field<string>("BARCODE")
                    select new
                    {

                        Order = ex.Field<string>("ORDER_CUST"),
                        Stock = ac.Field<string>("QTY_WH"),
                        Barcode = ex.Field<string>("BARCODE")
                    };

                    foreach (var q in query)
                    {
            dtAll.Rows.Add(q.Barcode, q.Stock, q.Order);

                    }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtAll;
```

This returns
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'.
At the select new block

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Use Linq JOIN on the two datatables.  I recommend putting the two datatables into a datagridview.DataSource = ds.Talbe[0] (also 1) so you can see the header names of the columns.  The Join uses the headers names to combine the two tables.

Comment: hey jdwng so I tried using join with no luck, it either goes crazy at me about using/not using enumerables or yelling at me about not using the correct casts? any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See code below and following webpage for joining tables : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

```
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();


            var results =
                from c1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                join c2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                   on c1.Field<int>("ID") equals c2.Field<int>("ID") into cs
                select new { Category = c1.Field<string>("ColB"), Fields = cs };
```

Comment: Hey JD, thanks so much but I used your snippet and changed the table names, but intellisense won't show CopyToDataTable, alternatively if I try datagridview.datasource = results; nothing shows? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: also JD in your method, I can't seem to select new anything for the c2 range, it's unrecognized?

Comment: For c2 see link I provided.  To see c2 you need to enumerate through cs using a for or a Seclect() method.  CopyToDataTable only works when the DataTable structure exists.  Since you have joined the two tables a new table is generated so you don't have a structure.  I usually in your case create a new DataTable and add columns to table in code.  Then take the linq results and put into new table.  You can also search web for "c# datatable anonymous linq" for solutions.

Comment: hey JD, your a legend!!!! and absolutely right in the end I cloned the datatables so all my fields were strings.

My HERO